# Botframework loop user first bot wait for message

Tags: loops, botframework

If user complete conversation, bot wait for user input. But I dont want wait.

This happen

1. Bot: Tell me a good joke
2. user: Can a kangaroo jump higher than a house? Of course, a house
   doesn’t  jump at all.
3. Bot: Thanks
4. User: Hallo!!!
5. Bot: Tell me a good hoke  (again same conversation)
6. ....

But i want this

1. Bot: Tell me a good joke
2. user: Can a kangaroo jump higher than a house? Of course, a house
   doesn’t  jump at all
3. Bot: Thanks
4. Bot: Tell me a good hoke  (again same conversation)
5. ....

   return Chain.From(() => FormDialog.FromForm(BuildForm, FormOptions.PromptInStart))

   ```
           .Switch(
              .
              //Code
              .
           )
           .Unwrap().PostToUser();
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You can send multiple messages before put the bot into **'wait'** state

```
connector.Conversations.ReplyToActivity(incomingMessage.CreateReply("Thanks", "en"));
connector.Conversations.ReplyToActivity(incomingMessage.CreateReply("Tell a good hoke", "en"));
```

https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/csharp/builder/sdkreference/routing.html#multiplereplies

Comment: It does not make sense. Can you explain your solution?

Comment: I think he's just saying that you can send your "thanks" to the user, followed up immediately with the prompt for "Tell a good joke" before you wait for user's response.  Seems like this is what you're asking for, unless your sample just oversimplified the problem